# R write.table com rbind

Tags: r

Olá,

Tenho as seguintes variáveis: ano, area e uma série de dados. A cada loop de area e ano, eu faço uma média dos meus dados.

```
for(area in 1:10){ 
   for(ano in 1:20){
      calculo_coeficiente<- mean(d) }}
```

** *d em função de area e ano*

A questão é que eu quero fazer um único write.table, com todas as variáveis e todos os loops, onde eu conseguisse o .txt:

```
area1 ano1 calculo_coeficiente1
area1 ano2 calculo_coeficiente2
area1 ano3 calculo_coeficiente3
....
area2 ano1 calculo_coeficiente1
area2 ano2 calculo coeficiente2
....
area3 ano1 calculo_coeficiente1
area3 ano2 calculo_coeficiente2
```

Tentei usando:

```
output<-rbind(data.frame(c(area),data.frame(ano),data.frame(coeficiente)),output)

write.table(output,"tabela.txt",sep=""),row.names =F,col.names=F)
```

e

```
output<- rbind(cbind(area[area],ano[area], media[area]))
output<- rbind(cbind(area[ano],ano[ano], media[ano]))
```

Mas não funcionou. Alguém saberia me dar uma luz?
Obrigada!

Comment: Não se percebe a estrutura dos dados. Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(area)` ou, se o vetor for muito grande, de `dput(head(area, 20))`? E o mesmo para `ano` e `calculo_coeficiente`. Sempre com `dput()`.

Comment: Parece não ser necessário `rbind`. `output <- data.frame(area, ano, calculo_coeficiente)` tem ar de chegar.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Me desculpe, é que meu código é bem mais complexo e envolve muitas outras coisas 'fora desse contexto', mas vou tentar explicar. Tenho uma area (length=1549) e um ano de (length=29) e uma serie de dados (d=28). A cada loop, area=1, ano=1, eu faço uma média de d. E assim, sucessivamente, area=1, ano=2.... O que eu preciso, é salvar um txt, com todas as infos de area, ano e a média dos meus dados. Ficou confuso? Qualquer coisa me avisa.

Comment: Tem um erro de sintaxe nesta linha `write.table(output,"tabela.txt",sep=""),row.names =F,col.names=F)`: você está fechando o parênteses duas vezes, mas só abre uma.

Comment: Obrigada @TomásBarcellos. Mas infelizmente esse é só um detalhe para salvar, o problema maior é na estruturação do loop e no 'write.table'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não posso comentar, por isso ponho como resposta.
Podes dar algumas data frames como exemplo para conseguir perceber o problema.

Será que ajuda?

```
output<- rbind(cbind(area, ano, coeficiente),output)
```

Edit!

```
> area = c(1:10)
> ano= c(2001:2010)
> 
> teste <- data.frame()
> for(area in 1:10){ 
+    for(ano in 2001:2010){
+       teste <<- rbind(cbind(area,ano, mean(area+ano)),teste) }}
> 
> 
> head(teste)
  area  ano   V3
1   10 2010 2020
2   10 2009 2019
3   10 2008 2018
4   10 2007 2017
5   10 2006 2016
6   10 2005 2015
```

Comment: Muito obrigada @João!

Comment: Editei a resposta com o rbind, em principio deve ajudar! Boa sorte!